# How do I formally document a C# Attribute in UML?

Tags: c#, attributes, uml

What is the proper way to document a C# Attribute on a class in a UML class diagram?

Comment: @Artur: if you have a problem, take it to http://meta.stackoverflow.com/, and then add a comment here with the link to your question there.

Comment: @John Saunders: Phank you, I think it will be helpful for you too

Comment: @John Sanders: Thanks, Stupid typos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't decided if this is my answer, but I figured I'd throw it out there for sake of discussion.  Does this look acceptable?

[image]

Its an instance of the attribute type with the metadata values put into tagged values below.  I just figured out how to add custom stereo types. The arrow is just a dependency arrow that is labeled as "applies".

Comment: This is a dependency, by the way, on a diagram above

Comment: You know, I've got a personal hater here, so i think it will not do the trick ;) I think you saw this obvious things first, and this looks like a dependency, so even dependency injection mechanisms sometimes can use attributes, that means something, actually ;)

Comment: I like your post. By the way, UML is desighend to be capable, at least, describe weak dependencies, for example, between C# classes and class attributes.

Comment: @Artur: This is dependency injection actually. I'm using MEF. ExportViewMetadataAttribute extends ExportAttribute.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is "standard", except that it uses a standard feature from UML:

Sparx Enterprise Architect, when reverse-engineering, for instance, a unit test class, uses tagged values for the attributes. A tagged value "`Attribute`" on the class, has the name of the attribute as a value, for instance, "`[TestClass]`". Similarly, "`Attribute = [TestMethod]`" is placed on the methods. An example would be:

```
[TestClass]
public class MyTests
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void DoSomeTest()
    {
    }
}
```

In this example, `[TestClass]` and `[TestMethod]` are .NET attributes (not UML attributes). They are short for `[TestClassAttribute]` and `[TestMethodAttribute]`. Both are classes deriving from the `System.Attribute` class.

An attribute simply adds metadata to the assembly. By itself, it has no runtime behavior.